# How to print a function using a click event

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, event-handling

I am doing the `Print all even numbers from 0 – 10` challange, I created a funciton that should take a usuers input and give the even number of it, if it's 10, 100, 1000, 10 000 etc.

I am trying to get the user input to print from the array by using an event listener, that when submit button is clicked, all numbers are printed in the
`outcome` html element

```
 <form id="form">
   <input class="input" type="text">
   <input class="submit" type="submit">
 </form>

 <div class="output">
   <p>Output</p>
   <div class="outcome"></div>
 </div>
```

```
//Empty Array
arrayEvenNum = []

/function that loops through input value and push to array
function loopInput(){
    let userInput = document.querySelector(".input").value

    for (let i = 0; i <= userInput; i+=2) {
       arrayEvenNum.push(i)
    }

    return userInput

}

let submit = document.querySelector(".submit")

submit.addEventListener("click",() => {
    //print numbers in array in HTML

})
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the text to the 'outcome' `div`, get the div as an element and add text to it - here is one way to do this within your submit event listener callback:

```
// This method returns an array of elements, get the first one
const outcome = document.getElementsByClassName("outcome")[0]; 

// Create a text node containing your results:
const textNode = document.createTextNode(arrayEvenNum.toString());

// Append the text node to the div
outcome.appendChild(textNode);
```

Comment: Thank you that solves the the printing part.